# RwLock deadlock and safety of the primitive

Tags: rust

In a textbook read/write lock, if a writer takes a lock, it blocks all new readers and waits for existing readers to exit. However, Rust docs suggest that some system-specific implementations can deadlock (while the textbook one can't?):

> The priority policy of the lock is dependent on the underlying operating system’s implementation, and this type does not guarantee that any particular policy will be used. In particular, a writer which is waiting to acquire the lock in write might or might not block concurrent calls to read [...]

([docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html)).

Curious if anyone has more details that could explain this difference in implementations or maybe how to select a desired safe policy? It seems like without a guarantee a deadlock is almost certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is saying the *fairness* of the lock is OS dependent. If the lock is unfair to writers, then a continuous stream of readers (even if they individually unlock and relock) could keep the writer from acquiring the lock. If this happens its not deadlocked, it is *starved*.

If this is a concern, you can consider using a fair lock like `parking-lot`'s [`RwLock`](https://docs.rs/parking_lot/latest/parking_lot/type.RwLock.html).

Answer (score -1):

Your textbook is correct, however I don't see any part of the documentation stating a deadlock may occur. The documentation states this since thread safety and concurrency is a big part of rust. However since Rust can not make any guarantees regarding system specific implementations beyond what other existing standards are available. If even a single compilation target may block with a system specific implementation, then it should be stated as such in the documentation since it could otherwise be count as undefined behavior in safe Rust.

But this really isn't cause for concern. A RwLock can offer better performance for many concurrent reads than a mutex by not blocking. Even if a system specific policy is problematic, you will at least have the protection provided by the type system enforcing that a `RwLock` only be `Sync` if its contents are also `Sync`.

```
// This is also the reason why a RwLock has extra requirements on Sync
impl<T: ?Sized + Send> Sync for Mutex<T> {...}
impl<T: ?Sized + Send + Sync> Sync for RwLock<T> {...}
```